# Error in importing an existing project in eclipse

Tags: android, import

I am using this code to run in the eclipse.[Search for Download the sample](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/optimizing-view.html#less)

After importing the downloaded project in the eclipse. I am getting error at

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
```

The eclipse not able to find the class *`Animation,ObjectAnimator and ValueAnimator`*

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: please help me out guys.

Comment: @Royston Pinto Can you please let me know that from where i can get the corrosponding jar file for above mentioned class???

Comment: These are valid libraries supported by android, however only API level 11 and upwards. Is your project target below this API?

Comment: Nope. My Api level target to 8

Comment: Then they wont work for you, switch to API level 11.

Answer (score 1):

Include your animation jar in the eclipse BuildPath. Right click on the Project go to `Buildpath->Configure Build Path ->Libraries` and add you jar. There is also a possibility that your Animator and other classes are mentioned with wrong package names. Check that out. It should solve the issue.

Comment: can you please provide the link for animator.jar file from where i can get this jar file?

Comment: Sorry but stil i am not able to find the jar file. could you please help me out"?